# Count number of rows on birt

Tags: count, birt

I have a dataset setup like this:

```
Number 
1
2
3
4
```

I want to get the number of rows on Birt. 
When I added the data to table and aggregated on table and count number number, I got result like it

```
Number of rows=4. 
Number of rows=4. 
Number of rows=4. 
Number of rows=4.
```

I can not figure out why it is displaying 4 rows instead of 1. I want an answer like this

```
Number of rows=4.
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You want to have that data not in the Table-Detail which is repeated per row but put it to the Table-Footer.